# Setting cmd.exe /V:ON flag without starting new instance

Tags: batch-file, cmd, flags

Is there any way to enable execution-time variable expansion for cmd.exe (normally done by typing `cmd /V:ON`) without starting a new instance of cmd.exe?

Similarly, can other settings/flags be changed on the fly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

There's also

```
setlocal enableextensions
```

which is the equivalent of `cmd /E:ON`.

Reference: `setlocal /?`.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
```